Does Simple Broker auto deletes the message queue in Stomp Websocket?
I am new to learning Websockets and how they work.
In my implementation of Websocket using Springboot (React Client), I am using one connection
[ ws://localhost:8080/intl-moa/ws-endpoint (for eg)]
I wish to send progress updates regarding each jobId which might take long to process at backend. Each jobId can be accessed by user who created it and all admins.
We planned to create destination topics like "/topic/{jobId}" and subscribe to required based on user sessionId.
Ques- 1 : I want to understand if it is possible to auto-delete the message queue using simplebroker once all message are consumed or topic is unsubscribed as we are expecting large number of jobId in our application ? How will the inactive queues affect the application ?
Ques- 2 : Can you please guide, how I can visualize the memory utilisation of these topic queues, scalability over multiple pods and performance when multiple users consume messages concurrently.
Attaching the config file and topic subscription.
Will greatly appreciate a quick help.
(https://i.sstatic.net/3qhJoflD.png)
topic image
